# add_image_size wont work after get_intermediate_image_sizes

Tags: images

I am using the function

```
get_intermediate_image_sizes()
```

to check if an image size already exists, and if not create it. However when I use

```
add_image_size( 'test3', 150, 150, true );
```

after the call to get_intermediate_image_sizes() the image size is not created. The image size is created if I call add_image_size() before get_intermediate_image_sizes()

Full code

http://pastebin.com/NMYHvzLn

Any ideas appreciated :)